# How can I find out if the response came from the edge server or the origin (CDN)

Tags: cdn

Is there a way to find out where the response response came from? From the CDN in Korea or my origin in L.A?

Example1:
Response headers:
Server: Apache

Example2:
Response headers
Server: AkamaiGHost

Are these responses both coming from Akamai, or is the Apache coming from my server (we are running Apache), but maybe Akamai are running Apache as well?

Thank you,

Comment: Ask your CDN provider.

Comment: both from Akamai, they use apache indeed. You see, the whole point of using CDN is to shelter your origin. If I could find your origin from a standard response, I would be able to bring down your whole service with a cheapest ddos. So you'd better describe what you actually trying to do?